# Random EWOULDBLOCKs generated in UDP non-blocking client/server pair with SIGIO-generated recvfroms

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp, asyncsocket

I'm building a UDP non-blocking client and server socket pair with SIGIO facilitating the reception of the data on the server. Here's my situation. I have a SIGIO activating when the client sends a message to me. However, the messages are approx. 3 bursts of 1024-byte packets (i.e. the client sends 3 packets all at once). I want the server to trigger on SIGIO on the first packet, and in the handler I have a while loop that goes through up to 2 of the 3 packets and reads them (for this current run). However, I have several runs of these 3 packet sends, and they are separated by 5 seconds. So I want the first packet to trigger the SIGIO, the while empties the buffer, and **inside the signal handler** I cancel the one SIGIO pending signal that might be caused from the remaining 3-1 packets on the first run, and re-enable SIGIO for the next run first packet (in 5 secs). It'll be easier to explain if you just look at the code:

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

static const unsigned int TIMEOUT_SECS = 2; // Seconds between retransmits

void error(const char *msg, const char *detail);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  if ((argc < 6) || (argc > 7))
    error("Parameter(s)", "<Server Address/Name> <Echo File> <Server Port/Service> <Maximum packet length> <Number of trials> [<Seconds between trials>]");

  char *server = argv[1];
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2], "rb");
  if (fp == NULL)
    error("Error opening file", "");

  fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_END);
  unsigned long stringlen = (getc(fp) == '\n' ? (ftell(fp) - 1) : ftell(fp));
  rewind(fp);

  char *string = malloc(stringlen * sizeof(char));
  if (string == NULL)
    error("malloc() failed", "");
  for (int i = 0; i < stringlen; i++) {
    *(string + i) = fgetc(fp);
  }
  printf("%lu\n", stringlen);

  fclose(fp);

  in_port_t service = (in_port_t) strtol(argv[3], NULL, 10);
  int maxpack = (int) strtol(argv[4], NULL, 10);
  int trials = (int) strtol(argv[5], NULL, 10); // must coordinate with server
  if (trials < 1)
    error("invalid trials parameter", "entered a nonpositive number");
  int sleeptime = (argc == 7) ? (int) strtol(argv[6], NULL, 10) : 5;

  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
  if (sock < 0)
    error("socket() failed", "");

  struct timeval timeout;
  timeout.tv_sec = TIMEOUT_SECS;
  timeout.tv_usec = 0;
  if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *) &timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
    error("setsockopt() failed", "");
  if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *) &timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
    error("setsockopt() failed", "");

  struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
  memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
  servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  int rc = inet_pton(AF_INET, server, &servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
  if (rc == 0)
    error("inet_pton() failed", "invalid address string");
  else if (rc < 0)
    error("inet_pton() failed", "");
  servAddr.sin_port = htons(service);

  int packnum = (int) ceil((double) stringlen / maxpack);
  for (int num = 0; num < trials; num++) {
    struct timespec start, end;
    uint64_t diff;
    ssize_t numBytes;
    for (int i = 0; i < packnum; i++) {
      if (i == 0)
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
      numBytes = sendto(sock, string + i * maxpack, maxpack, 0, (struct sockaddr* ) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
      if (numBytes < 0)
        error("sendto() failed", "");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in fromAddr;
    socklen_t fromAddrlen = sizeof(fromAddr);
    char buffer[strlen(argv[3]) + 1 + packnum + 1];
    memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    do {
      numBytes = recvfrom(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &fromAddr, &fromAddrlen);
      if (numBytes < 0)
        error("recvfrom() failed", "");
      buffer[numBytes] = '\0';
    } while ((int) strtol(buffer, NULL, 10) == num);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    diff = 1000000000L * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;

    printf("Received: %s\n", buffer);
    printf("Time: %f ms\n", (double) (diff / (double) 1000000));
    sleep(sleeptime);
  }

  free(string);
  close(sock);

  exit(0);
}

void error(const char *msg, const char *detail) {
  fputs(msg, stderr);
  if (*detail != '\0') {
    fputs(": ", stderr);
    fputs(detail, stderr);
  }
  fputc('\n', stderr);
  exit(1);
}
```

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define ITOA_BASE_N (sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT + 2)

void error(const char *msg, const char *detail);
void PrintSocketAddress(const struct sockaddr *address, FILE *stream);
void SIGIOHandler(int signalType);
char * itoa_base(char *s, int x, int base);
void recvflush(int sockfd);

#define ITOA(x,b) itoa_base((char [ITOA_BASE_N]){0} , (x), (b))

int sock, acknum, maxpack; // GLOBAL for signal handler
volatile sig_atomic_t run, packets; // VOLATILE FOR signal handler modification
struct sigaction handler;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  if (argc != 5)
    error("Parameter(s)", "<Server Port/Service> <Number of ACKs> <Maximum packet length> <Number of trials>");

  in_port_t service = (in_port_t) strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
  acknum = (int) strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);
  maxpack = (int) strtol(argv[3], NULL, 10);
  int trials = (int) strtol(argv[4], NULL, 10); // must coordinate with client
  run = 0;

  sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
  if (sock < 0)
    error("socket() failed", strerror(errno));

  struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
  memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
  servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  servAddr.sin_port = htons(service);

  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)
    error("bind() failed", strerror(errno));

  handler.sa_handler = SIGIOHandler;
  if (sigfillset(&handler.sa_mask) < 0)
    error("sigfillset() failed", "mask not set");
  handler.sa_flags = 0;

  if (sigaction(SIGIO, &handler, 0) < 0)
    error("sigaction() failed", "SIGIO behavior unable to be modified");

  if (fcntl(sock, F_SETOWN, getpid()) < 0)
    error("Unable to set process owner to us", "");

  if (fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK | FASYNC) < 0)
    error(
        "Unable to put client sock into non-blocking/async mode", "");

  recvflush(sock);

  for (;;) {
    if (run == trials) {
      close(sock);
      exit(0);
    }
    printf(".");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
  }
}

void SIGIOHandler(int signalType) {
  printf("SIGIO\n");
  packets = 0;
  run++;
  struct sockaddr_in clntAddr;
  socklen_t clntLen = sizeof(clntAddr);
  ssize_t numBytes;
  //FILE *fp = fopen("output.txt", "ab");
  //if (fp == NULL)
    //error("Error opening file", "");
  char buffer[maxpack + 1];
  //char *output = malloc(2000 * (maxpack + 1) * sizeof(char));
  //if (output == NULL)
    //error("malloc() failed", "");
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  //memset(output, 0, sizeof(output));
  while (packets < 2) { // read up to 2 packets (1024 bytes each) from buffer
    numBytes = recvfrom(sock, buffer, maxpack, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &clntLen);
    if (numBytes < 0) {
      if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK) // only acceptable error
        error("recvfrom() failed", strerror(errno));
      else
        printf("%d EWOULDBLOCK", numBytes);
    } else {
      if (numBytes > 0) {
        packets++;
        buffer[numBytes] = '\0';
        //memmove(output + maxpack * packets, buffer, strlen(buffer));
      }
      printf("Run-Packet numBytes: %d-%d %d\n", run, packets, numBytes);
      printf("\t%s\n", buffer);
    }
  }
  sigset_t mask;
  sigpending(&mask);
  if (sigismember(&mask, SIGIO))
    printf("pending SIGIO signal\n");
  printf("setting ignore\n");
  struct sigaction change;
  change.sa_handler = SIG_IGN; // set ignore handler to cancel pending SIGIO signals from 1024 - 1 packets
  if (sigfillset(&change.sa_mask) < 0)
    error("sigfillset() failed", "mask not set");
  change.sa_flags = 0;
  if (sigaction(SIGIO, &change, 0) < 0)
    error("sigaction() failed", "SIGIO behavior unable to be modified");
  sigpending(&mask);
  if (sigismember(&mask, SIGIO))
    printf("pending SIGIO signal\n"); // should NOT show up
  recvflush(sock); // flush ignored bytes
  //for (int i = 0; i < strlen(output); i++)
    //putc(output[i], fp);
  //putc('\0', fp);

  //fclose(fp);
  //free(output);

  char *ack = ITOA(run, 10);
  char *append = ITOA(packets, 10);
  strcat(ack, "/"); // fix client side
  strcat(ack, append);
  for (int i = 0; i < acknum; i++) {
    numBytes = sendto(sock, ack, sizeof(ack), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, clntLen);
    if (numBytes < 0)
      error("sendto() failed", strerror(errno));
  }

  if (sigaction(SIGIO, &handler, 0) < 0)
        error("sigaction() failed", "SIGIO behavior unable to be modified"); // reenable SIGIO for subsequent runs

  printf("HERE\n");
}

char * itoa_base(char *s, int x, int base) {
  s += ITOA_BASE_N - 1;
  *s = '\0';
  if (base >= 2 && base <= 36) {
    int x0 = x;
    do {
      *(--s) = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[abs(x % base)];
      x /= base;
    } while (x);
    if (x0 < 0) {
      *(--s) = '-';
    }
  }
  return s;
}

void recvflush(int sockfd) {
  ssize_t num;
  do {
    num = recvfrom(sockfd, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (num < 0 && errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
      error("recvfrom() failed", strerror(errno));
  } while (errno != EWOULDBLOCK);
}
```

Now, I start the server first with parameters `8080 10 1024 2` and pipe it to look at the first 10,000 chars using `| head -c 10000`. Then, I start the client with parameters `192.168.4.101 test.txt 8080 1024 2`. The `test.txt` is filled with approx. 3000 junk characters, which should split into 3 packets of 1024 (notice `ceil` in client). However, whenever I send the information, a very peculiar thing happens.

Sometimes, everything works perfectly and I receive the output as expected, with 5 seconds in between buffer `printf`s. Other times, it screws up and generates a EWOULDBLOCK error (see `printf("%d EWOULDBLOCK", numBytes);` in server code) forever. Every time it generates this error, it still reads the ignored packet (since I'm only reading 2 of the 3 packets and flushing the rest with `recvflush`) even though I'm flushing the receive buffer. Supposedly, `recvflush` clears out the entire buffer to prepare for subsequent runs but for some reason the ignored packet stays there. Help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that all 3 packets are already in the socket buffer at the time the SIGIO triggers your signal  handler. But the SIGIO gets triggered on the first packet which means there might be only a single packet or two packets in the socket buffer.

Assuming there is only a single packet the second `recv` will fail with EWOULDBLOCK since there are no more packets. Similar the `recv` in `recvflush` will fail since the missing packets are not there yet. And no SIGIO will be triggered either if the packets are not there so any calls of `sigpending` will not be able to detect that there are outstanding data.

Comment: Hmm... what do you think could be the problem? I thought that the 3 packets reaching the buffer by the time SIGIO triggers was a vaild assumption because I have a traffic shaper in the middle that counts the packets passed through and every time the client sends the 3 packet bursts it logs the 3 before SIGIO triggers. I'm not sure. _Do you know of a better solution?_

Comment: IMHO a better solution would be to avoid signal handlers like the plague.  They are tricky to get right (e.g. there are lots of things that are not safe to do inside a signal handler, and it's not always obvious when you are breaking a handler-safety rule), they are non-portable, they don't mesh well with multithreading, and since you're using non-blocking I/O they aren't necessary.

Comment: @JonathanLee: I agree with JeremyFriesner that signals are bad. An approach using select, poll, epoll, kqueue or similar is preferable - and also has probably less overhead. Still, the main problem is that you are making unfounded assumptions about how many packets are in the socket buffer. Instead of assuming that there are three packets inside the buffer you should actually make sure that they are, i.e. retry on EWOULDBLOCK after the socket got readable again and count how many packets you skip. Also, since UDP is unreliable you also have to deal with packet loss, reordering or duplication.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner @Steff So how about a multi-threading approach? Maybe something that could spawn a child thread, deals with the bytes in the buffer, and kills itself as it waits for the next run? Or is the multiplexing method with `select`, `poll`, `epoll`, `kqueue`, or others better? To clarify, the server with have at most two possible clients communicating through UDP, but mainly one.

Comment: In my experience a single thread, handling the UDP socket and any other required sockets via select() and non-blocking I/O works fine.  If the UDP traffic is expected to be particularly high-volume, it might be worth the extra complexity to spawn a separate thread dedicated specifically to handling the UDP traffic (that reduces the risk of UDP socket buffers overflowing and dropping UDP packets).  If you do use a separate thread, you should keep the thread around rather than ending it and spawning a new thread, as spawning/reaping threads is rather expensive.

Comment: @JonathanLee: The problem you have is not if threads or poll or sigio or whatever should be used. The point is instead that you should not make any unfounded assumptions about which packets are already available in the socket buffer. If threads or poll (or a combination of both) are the best approach is a different question and should asked as such (i.e. not discussed here in the comments), and probably one where you gets lots of different opinions since some prefer threads will others prefer an event-based approach.